# How can we develop a matrix in my program to rectify the error

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Input #`SaveRating.csv`

```
  userId    9   71  204 251 667 980 1497 1599
    18      3   0   0   0   0   0   0     0
    32      0   0   4   0   0   0   0     0
    49      0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0
    62      0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0
    70      0   0   0   0   5   0   0     0
    73      0   0   0   0   0   0   0     1
    95      0   0   0   0   0   0   0     0
    103     0   1   0   0   0   0   0     0
```

i want to develop a table which will look like the below one
**Output**

```
movieId    9     71  204  251  667  980 1497 1599
       9
       71 
       204
       251
       667
       980
       1947
       1599
```

This to be present in a csv then i will place my calculated values here

for that i have written the #`code`

```
movie_pivot = movie.pivot_table(index='movieId', columns='movieId', values='rating', fill_value=0.0)
```

but not getting the desired result

Comment: Can you provide entire code? need to know how movie is constructed.

Comment: @White i want to construct the movie-movie matrix for the i have used the pivot_table and facing the error